# Uniqness of convergence in distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose that $F_1 ,F_2 ,.... ,F$ and $G$ are distribution function and

that $F_n \to F$  in distribution and$ F_n \to G$ in distribution  as $n\to \infty $

prove that $F=G$

what idea can i solve it ?

Answer (score 0):

Equivalently, $(F_n(x))_{n\geq1}$ converges to $F(x)$ (and $G(x)$) at every point of continuity of $F(x)$. Now show that this set of points is dense and use right-continuity of $F$ and $G$ to get $F=G$.

Comment: Fn→F in distribution how i use it type of convergence i dont understanded what you mean ?

Comment: I’m saying that $F_n$ is an increasing, right-continuous function from $\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,1]$, so we can just treat them as functions.